# How x509chain works in C#? What is purpose of using it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, x509certificate

I have implement client certificate based security in C#. Everything is clear and working good for me. I was finding perfect way to verify client certificate on server side, through which i came to x509Chain. But i am not clear about How it exactly works? How can we configure it? Is it secure way to verify certificate?

Any help will be Appreciated! Thanks!

**Note:** By theoretical point of view, i have read my documents on that but i am not sure for it's functionality. Please provide practical example and guide for that.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of theory I wrote some time ago: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3147.certificate-chaining-engine-cce.aspx

This article describes what is certificate chaining engine (CCE) and how it works in Windows in general. It is based on [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) and Microsoft-specific implementation of certificate chaining engine. .NET uses native CryptoAPI functions, so X509Chain behaves in the same way as in native CryptoAPI.

Comment: Great Article! Sill i have question in mind that in C#, there is option i.e. X509RevocationMode.Online, Does it mean that it will cross check Certificate Issuer Chain Automatically? Is that enough to check certificate security? Please give me some clearance on this. Thanks!

Comment: CCE default behavior is to use locally cached valid CRL/OCSP response (if exist) for revocation checking. This option instructs chaining engine to download CRL from online source even if local cache already contains valid CRL/OCSP response.

Comment: And yes, X509Chain is sufficient to validate the certificate. If necessary, you can apply additional application-specific checks after executing CCE. If CCE fails, then you can safely reject presented certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Since i am newbie to client certificate i am confused about code/certificate configuration.

Comment: it depends exclusively on your application and application needs. CCE checks certificate for compliance with RFC5280, while your application may require additional checks. You need to formulate more specific question.

Comment: I am implementing code to verify client certificate in my Web API. By so many RND i was able to create self signed certi, pass it from test client application, receive it from API by IIS configuration and code. I don't have any specific requirement for this configuration. My task is to implement valid client certificate security in our API service.

Comment: You can't trust arbitrary client certificate. You will have to check certificate's Subject (or Subject Alternative Names extension) to authenticate the client somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91583/discussion-between-dsa-and-cryptoguy).

Comment: Checking only certificate Subject/Issuer/HashString is not valid way to authenticate user. I want to use pre-defined concrete method to verify my client/client certificate.
If you have time, can you please help me out on chat box for this validation thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `X509Chain` does not work reliably for scenarios where you do not have the root certificate in the trusted CA store on the machine.

Others will advocate using bouncy castle. I wanted to avoid bringing in another library just for this task, so I wrote my own.

As see in [RFC3280 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1) the certificate is a `ASN1` encoded structure, and at it's base level is comprised of only 3 elements.

1. The "TBS" (to be signed) certificate
2. The signature algorithm
3. and the signature value

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     tbsCertificate TBSCertificate,
     signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
     signatureValue BIT STRING
}
```

C# actually has a handy tool for parsing ASN1, the [System.Formats.Asn1.AsnDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asndecoder?view=net-7.0).

Using this, we can extract these 3 elements from the certificate to verify the chain.

The first step was extracting the certificate signature, since the `X509Certificate2` class does not expose this information and it is necessary for the purpose of certificate validation.

**Example code to extract the signature value part:**

```cs
public static byte[] Signature(
    this X509Certificate2 certificate,
    AsnEncodingRules encodingRules = AsnEncodingRules.BER)
{
    var signedData = certificate.RawDataMemory;
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        signedData.Span,
        encodingRules,
        out var offset,
        out var length,
        out _
    );

    var certificateSpan = signedData.Span[offset..(offset + length)];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        certificateSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var tbsOffset,
        out var tbsLength,
        out _
    );

    var offsetSpan = certificateSpan[(tbsOffset + tbsLength)..];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        offsetSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var algOffset,
        out var algLength,
        out _
    );

    return AsnDecoder.ReadBitString(
        offsetSpan[(algOffset + algLength)..],
        encodingRules,
        out _,
        out _
    );
}
```

The next step is to extract the TBS certificate. This is the original data which was signed.

**example code to extract the TBS certificate data:**

```cs
public static ReadOnlySpan<byte> TbsCertificate(
    this X509Certificate2 certificate,
    AsnEncodingRules encodingRules = AsnEncodingRules.BER)
{
    var signedData = certificate.RawDataMemory;
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        signedData.Span,
        encodingRules,
        out var offset,
        out var length,
        out _
    );

    var certificateSpan = signedData.Span[offset..(offset + length)];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        certificateSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var tbsOffset,
        out var tbsLength,
        out _
    );

    // include ASN1 4 byte header to get WHOLE TBS Cert
    return certificateSpan.Slice(tbsOffset - 4, tbsLength + 4);
}
```

You may notice that when extracting the TBS certiifcate I needed to include the ASN1 header in the data, this is because the signature of the TBS Certificate INCLUDES this data (this annoyed me for a while).

For the first time in history, the Microsoft does not impede us with their API design, and we are able to obtain the [Signature Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.signaturealgorithm?view=net-7.0) directly from the `X509Certificate2` object. Then we just need to decide to what extend we are going to implement different hash algorithms.

```cs
var signature = signed.Signature();
var tbs = signed.TbsCertificate();
var alg = signed.SignatureAlgorithm;

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpnap/a48b02b2-2a10-4eb0-bed4-1807a6d2f5ad
switch (alg)
{
    case { Value: var value } when value?.StartsWith("1.2.840.113549.1.1.") ?? false:
        return signedBy.GetRSAPublicKey()?.VerifyData(
            tbs,
            signature,
            value switch {
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.12" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA384,
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.13" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
                _ => throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg)
            },
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1
        ) ?? false;
    case { Value: var value } when value?.StartsWith("1.2.840.10045.4.3.") ?? false:
        return signedBy.GetECDsaPublicKey()?.VerifyData(
            tbs,
            signature,
            value switch
            {
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.2" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.3" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA384,
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.4" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
                _ => throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg)
            },
            DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence
        ) ?? false;
    default: throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg);
}
```

As shown in the code above, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpnap/a48b02b2-2a10-4eb0-bed4-1807a6d2f5ad is a good resource to see the mapping of algorithms and OIDs.

Another thing you should be aware of is that there are some articles out there that claim that for elliptical curve algorithms, microsoft expects a `R,S` formatted key instead of a DER formatted key. I tried to convert the key to this format but it ultimately didn't work. What I discovered was that it was necessary to use the `DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence` parameter.

Additional certificate checks, like "not before" and "not after", or CRL and OCSP checks can be done in addition to the chain verification.

Comment: I would normally advocate using Bouncycastle, but anyway your implementation is nice.